# What is Classvalue in KNN?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, knn

I am a beginner in data science, and programming I am trying to do a program but I don't understand the question.

the question - you should write a function that takes train and test data as NumPy ndarrays, and a k-value as an integer, and returns the class-values of the test data.

I understood that I need to write a function that takes test, train,k-values. but what does returning the classvalue of test data means?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMasc.png)

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what classvalue could be, do you mean class type?  which can be found by using ```type(element)```

Comment: Or in the case of numpy by using dtype

Comment: I don't know what's class value is, in the question, I was asked to return the class value of the test data.

Comment: so i should just return the datatype?

Comment: @itpror, this isn't a numpy array property.  It requires some sort of analysis of the data, possibly using the `knn` package.  The course/tutorial should explain this.

Comment: You need to spend time reading the background materials for this `knn classification`.  The course shouldn't be asking you to do something that it hasn't already prepared you for.  SO cannot replace that kind of instruction.